# Why isn't Salesforce Data Event available in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to use Salesforce Data Events in my Journey however I cannot see the activity in my journey canvas.

I have the Marketing Cloud connector installed and all the relevant objects sycned already.

I am using v213.0 from the AppExchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked, if the [Connected App](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/authentication/upgrade_to_connected_app/) is enabled? I have seen this issue, when the accounts (MC and SC) are not correctly authenticated with each other. So you get the Synchronised DEs, but don't have the ability to use Journey Builder Salesforce Data events.

You might also want to [clear the OAuth token](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214335&type=1), and reconnect the integration - this has also proved helpful for me before.

If neither work, you might want to reach out to SF support.

Brgds
Lukas

Comment: Had to raise a case with Salesforce in the end, turns out it was a setting on their end that they had to switch on (or thats what SF support claimed).